# How to fix 'allennlp.common.checks.ConfigurationError' in running scibert projec?

Tags: python, allennlp

File"/home/yangzhiwei/workshop/scibert/scibert/models/bert_text_classifier.py", line 15, in  from text_classifier import TextClassifier File "/home/yangzhiwei/workshop/scibert/scibert/models/text_classifier.py", line 15, in  class TextClassifier(Model):File "/home/yangzhiwei/workshop/scibert/src/allennlp/allennlp/common/registrable.py", line 49, in add_subclass_to_registry raise configurationError(message)
allennlp.common.checks.ConfigurationError: 'Cannot register text_classifier as Model; name already in use for TextClassifier'

Comment: source code :   https://github.com/allenai/scibert

Comment: it would be much better if you could add it as an issue over there https://github.com/allenai/scibert/issues/new